# How to set a restriction to WPF IntegerUpDown toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, integerupdown

I have two WPF `IntegerUpDown` toolkit and I would like to set to one of the toolkit a restriction , the maximum of the second `IntegerUpDown` toolkit should be equals to the value of the first `IntegerUpDown` toolkit.

I choose `Value_changed` event to do this , but I got this exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

This my code :

```
   private void minimumatt_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        
        {
            maximumatt.Maximum = minimumatt.Value;

        }
```

Xaml code:

```
   <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown  ValueChanged="minimumatt_ValueChanged" Value="0" Minimum="0" x:Name="minimumatt" MinWidth="100" />
                                    
   <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="0" Minimum="0" x:Name="maximumatt" MinWidth="100"   />
```

How can I add a restriction to the `IntgerUpDown` WPF toolkit control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you cannot bind the [`Maximum`](https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit%7EXceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.UpDownBase%601%7EMaximum.html) directly to the [`Value`](https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit%7EXceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.UpDownBase%601%7EValue.html) of the other control?

```
<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="minimumatt" 
                          Value="0" 
                          Minimum="0" />
                                    
<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="maximumatt" 
                          Value="0" 
                          Minimum="0" 
                          Maximum="{Binding ElementName=minimumatt, 
                                            Path=Value
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```