# Why the UpdateSourceTrigger=Propertychanged dose not work correctly in IntegerUpdown?

Tags: wpf, xaml, numericupdown, updatesourcetrigger

My question is based on [How to set a restriction to WPF IntegerUpDown toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804384/how-to-set-a-restriction-to-wpf-integerupdown-toolkit/66805258#66805258) that I've posted a while ago.

I have two WPF `IntegerUpdown` controls, one represents the maximum number and the other represents the minimum number , the first should be greater than the second and the second should be less than the first.

The given solution by @D M in the first question solve my problem

```
    <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="minimumatt" 
                          Value="0" 
                          Minimum="0" />
                                    
<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="maximumatt" 
                          Value="0" 
                          Minimum="0" 
                          Maximum="{Binding ElementName=minimumatt, 
                                            Path=Value
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

But this can be only one when I click outside the control , the scenario that should be achieved is when the user selects a number in minimum `IntegerUpdown` control greater than the number that already exist in maximum , the number should be set to `0` or default when the user lost focus by mouse at that moment.

I already tested this solution:

```
 Maximum="{Binding ElementName=minimumatt, 
                                                Path=Value
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
```

But the event does not fired.

What can I do in this case?

For example , in this case when the user put `18` in min , the value should be changed in lost focus event, what worked now is that the user has to click outside this control to get the default value in minimum `IntegerUpdown`

[image]

**Update**:

I found an event (Mouseleave_event) that can be used to update the value in real time ( without clicking on other controls ) but I did not have any idea how can I use this event with Propertychanged , how can I do this?

Comment: What "event" do you expect to get fired? The value should be reset when the control loses focus and the focus isn't lost until you click outside the control.

Comment: I've update my question , the event that I would like to applied is `MouseLeave_event`

Comment: Then you need to hook up an event handler for that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found an event (Mouseleave_event) that can be used to update the value in real time ( without clicking on other controls ) but I did not have any idea how can I use this event with Propertychanged , how can I do this?

`UpdateSourceTrigger` is a property of the binding that controls when the source property, `Value` in this case, is updated. It doesn't raise any `MouseLeave` event for you.

If you want to handle an event, you should hook up an event handler for it and implement the handler in your code-behind class as usual:

```
<wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown x:Name="maximumatt" 
                          Value="0" 
                          Minimum="0" 
                          Maximum="{Binding Value, ElementName=minimumatt}"
                          MouseLeave="maximumatt_MouseLeave"/>
```

Comment: That what I have already done it, thank you

Comment: Yes I have fixed before you even give me the answer, but in any case I thank you.